# Help Understanding Provided Solution

Tags: functions, modular-arithmetic

I struggled with this problem for awhile before finally giving in and looking at the solution:

"Let $n > 1$ be an integer, $A = \mathbb{Z}/n$ the integers modulo $n$ and $G$ the set of maps

$\tau (a, b) : A \to A; \;\;\; \overline{x} \mapsto \overline{ax + b}$

where $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $(a, n) = 1$. Here $\overline{x}$ is the congruence class of the integer $x$. Prove that each element of G is a well-defined permutation of $A$."

So, I have two major questions. The first involves showing that each such function $\tau$ is well-defined. It seems to me that since $\tau$ is a function of $a$ and $b$, one must show that its image is unaffected by changes of representation for $a$ and $b$; however, the solution rather opaquely examines the effect of changing the representation of $x$ instead.

Secondly, and much more frustratingly, I feel that the solution's method of showing injectivity is nonstandard. Rather than showing that

$\tau (a,b) = \tau (c,d) \implies a = c, \;\; b = d$,

it shows that

$\tau (a,b) = \tau (c,d) \implies \overline{a} = \overline{c}, \;\; \overline{b} = \overline{d}$,

and somehow takes the liberty of using specially-picked $x$ to establish even this weaker fact. To make this more clear, here is the entire solution:

"First $\overline{ax + b} = \overline{a} \cdot \overline{x} + \overline{b}$, so $\tau (a,b)$ is well-defined; that is the definition does not depend on the choice of representative $x$ for $\overline{x}$.

We show that $\tau$ is bijective. First let's check that $\tau (a,b) = \tau (c,d)$ iff $\overline{a} = \overline{c}$ and $\overline{b} = \overline{d}$. If $\overline{x}\tau (a,b) = \overline{x} \tau (c,d)$, then $\overline{ax} + \overline{b} = \overline{cx} + \overline{d}$, so in particular for $\overline{x} = 0$ we have $\overline{b} = \overline{d}$. Then, taking $\overline{x} = 1$, we get $\overline{a} = \overline{c}$. This shows injectivity."

Yet another problem is that I have no idea what $\overline{x}\tau (a,b)$ is supposed to mean. However, it appears twice, so I feel that it is not a typo.

I am clearly missing something, or the solution is seriously flawed. I'm hoping it's the former. Thanks in advance!

P.S. I know that more is required to show bijectivity; fortunately, I actually understand what the solution is saying there!

Comment: Note that $\tau (a,b)$ is a function with variable $\overline{x}$, the $a$,$b$ are parameters which characterise the elements of $G$ (i.e. which function you are considering).  $\overline{x}\tau (a,b)$ means $\tau (a,b)(\overline{x})$, simply the author writes the variable on the left as some do.

Comment: Their method of showing injectivity is correct, but perhaps it should be made more clear to the reader than your set of maps $G$ is not genuinely indexed by $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ i.e. you don't actually get a different map for every $(a,b).$ In fact, the $(a,b)$ is the same as the $(a+kn, b+ln)$ map for any $k,l.$ So there are really only $n^2$ maps in $G.$